# Preprocessor keeping macros

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I want to preprocess C++ header files *keeping* all macros verbatim in the output text.

For that, I need a C preprocessor-like program that performs these tasks:

- store in memory macros from `#define` directives;
- recursively follow `#include` directives;
- evaluate conditions in `#if` and `#ifdef` directives;
- suppress the code in inactive portions of `#if` .. `#else` .. `#endif` blocks;
- (optionally) remove `/* .. */` and `//` comments;
- remove all remaining directives lines.

But the macros *must not* be replaced in the output. Or alternatively, the preprocessor may take in argument a list of macro names that shall not be replaced.

This may sound weird, but I have a good reason for that. I have a series of Perl scripts able to analyze preprocessed C++ class headers. And I use some macros to tell them for example which methods to export.

I haven't found a preprocessor program able to perform what I need, so I wrote a Perl 
script. The latter actually works, but is slow and non standard. I am looking for a better alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `gcc -E` to run the preprocessor manually. This will expand all the macros but that's not a problem.

What you want is special macros for the time when you need the output for your Perl scripts. Try this:

```
#ifdef PERL_PREPROCESSING
# define EXPORT(...) PERL_EXPORT
#else
# define EXPORT(...) ...normal C code...
#endif
```

So the idea is that you call `gcc -E -DPERL_PREPROCESSING` to switch some of the macros to produce output that your perl scripts can locate. The macros will be expanded as usual.

**[EDIT]** If you don't want to pollute your sources with Perl-specific macros, use this trick: Create a folder which contains the header file with the Perl versions of the macros and include this folder before every other folder with `-I`. `gcc` will then ignore the standard header file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using *nix you can use the grep command to find all the #defines in the directory

```
grep -R . '#define'
```

For the preprocessing required, use gcc -E.

Comment: gcc -E will replace macros! And I am not searching for macro definitions but macro usage.